# Remove menu bar wrap on smaller screen sizes

Tags: html, css

My centered menu bar wraps on screens smaller than desktop mode [picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcLPY.png) and I've tried several css code to make menu items appear on a single line which have not worked. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the bit of code I added in my CSS editor to center the navigation bar:

```
#navigation {
position: relative;
}
#main-nav {
clear: left;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
text-align: center;
}
.nav li {
display: block;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
right: 24%;
}
.nav li:hover, .nav li.hover {
position: relative;
}
.nav li ul li {
left: 0;
}
```

I noticed especially that the .nav li part controls the positioning of the navigation bar.

My html code for the navigation bar is below:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 footer-sidebar-wrap">
                            <aside id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><h3 class="widget-title">Menu</h3><div class="menu-primary-menu-container"><ul id="menu-primary-menu-1" class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-260"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-116"><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-113"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-114"><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-115"><a href="account.html">Account</a></li>
</ul></div></aside>                     </div>
```

The full css code for the navigation bar is here:

```
.page .navbar-custom {
    background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, .9) !important;

}
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, .9);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 11px;
    -webkit-transition: background, padding 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: background, padding 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: background, padding 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: background, padding 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: background, padding 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;

}

.navbar a {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: color 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: color 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: color 0.125s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar-custom .sub-menu,
.navbar-custom .children {
    background: rgba(26, 26, 26, .9);
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .sub-menu li,
.navbar-custom .children li  {
    list-style:none;
}

.navbar-custom .sub-menu li a,
.navbar-custom .children li a  {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li > a {
    position: relative;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

.navbar-custom .sub-menu > li > a,
.navbar-custom .children > li > a  {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(73, 71, 71, 0.15) !important;
    padding: 11px 15px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #999;
}

.navbar-custom .sub-menu .sub-menu,
.navbar-custom .children .children  {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(73, 71, 71, 0.15);
    left: 100%;
    right: auto;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .sub-menu.left-side .sub-menu,
.navbar-custom .children.left-side .children {
    border: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(73, 71, 71, 0.15);
    right: 100%;
    left: auto;
}

.navbar-custom .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav .open > a,
.navbar-custom .nav .open > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav .open > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .sub-menu > li > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .sub-menu > li > a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .sub-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .children > li > a:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) !important;
}

.navbar-custom .menu-item-has-children-toggle:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 'ElegantIcons';
    font-size: 9px;
    content: "\43";
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav .menu-item-has-children>a:after,
.navbar-nav .page_item_has_children>a:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 ElegantIcons;
    font-size: 9px;
    content: "\43";
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.navbar-nav .sub-menu,
.navbar-nav .children {
    min-width: 180px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.navbar-right ul {
    text-align: left;
}

/* Navbar search */

.menu-item-has-children-search {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}

.menu-item-has-children-search .form-control {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.search-btn {
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1px;
    width: 42px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 38px;
    font-size: 14px;
    outline: none;
    color: #999;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Comment: add your remaining codes i.e. HTML .

Comment: hi @frnt. They were there but I removed them as I thought they will be confusing. I have added them back. Thanks

Comment: You can put `white-space:nowrap;` on your `ul` tag. This will prevent your li to wrap around

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because your `<li>` elements are exceeding the width of the parent `<ul>` element.

I imagine you could use

`li {
   white-space: nowrap;
}`

This will stop the wrap behavior, however, will not be centered.

I would solve this issue with media queries, or making your parent `<ul>` element wider in general.

To use media queries use the following template:

`@media (max-width: 1000px) { 
//place the CSS you want to be activated when the screen is smaller than 1000px here 
    ul{ 
        width: 1000px;
    } 
    li{ 
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}`

One other thing that could occur is white-space between `<li>` or `<h3>` elements. The reason this is a problem is if those six `<li>` or `<h3>` tags' width all equal 100%, then those extra spaces will go over 100% width making the last element fall to the next line. The below code might do the trick.

```
h3 {
padding:0;
margin:0;
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot @chris. I'm however very new to css, so I don't understand when you say place the CSS you want to be activated when the screen is small here. I have edited the question to show only the code which I used to center the navigation bar. I hope this will help with getting code sorted.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be some help, a media query is a pretty awesome tool in CSS I highly encourage you take some time to read up on them, they're pretty amazing when dealing with responsive design.

Comment: As for put the code you want activated in here. Anything between the curly braces of a media query will only show in your web page if the media query evaluates as true. So only when the browser width is less than 1000px will the css inside those curly braces be applied

Comment: Hi @Chris I tried the code and unfortunately it didn't work :(. I tried putting the nowrap code in the .nav li part of the first code I pasted, then I added the media query through css editor but nothing happened. I also tried the media query alone and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Is there any reason your `.nav li{}` css contains a `right: 24%;` at first glance, that looks like it will skew everything.

Comment: that actually helped me center the navigation bar. I tried everything and that's the only thing that worked. The bar was originally aligned right but I centered it with bit of code, putting in the 24% did the trick.

Comment: Hi @chris that bit of code was was I used to center the navigation bar. It was originally aligned right and I tried all the code I could find online and they didn't work until this one. Changing the right to 24% was what eventually centered the bar.

Comment: I also tried your edited code and it did not work. It's so frustrating trying to sort this out.